# Haskellのwaiについて

Tags: api, http, haskell

Haskellでwai,warpを使ってapiサーバーを作りたいと考えたのですが
requestをByteStringに直して関数に渡したいのですがうまくいきません
よろしくお願いします

```
app :: Application
app request respond = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
    "/"     -> htmlIndex
    "/raw"  -> plainIndex
    _       -> function $ rawPathInfo request

function :: ByteString -> Response
function req = responseLBS
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    req
```

Answer (score 3):

これは、おそらく、正格ByteStringと遅延ByteStringとの、型の不一致ですね。
それぞれ、モジュール名も含めて書くと、つぎのようになります。

- Data.ByteString.ByteString
- Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString

これらは別の型です。対応としては、関数Data.ByteString.Lazy.fromStrictで、関数rawPathInfoの返り値を変換してやればいいでしょう。

対話環境に読み込める定義ファイルで例を示します。

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

app :: Application
app request respond = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
        rp -> function rp

function :: BS.ByteString -> Response
function req = responseLBS
        undefined
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        (LBS.fromStrict req)
```